# PHP crashes do not get to log, no matter what I do

Tags: php

Ubuntu 16.06 - Apache 2 - PHP-FPM - PHP 7.1

in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` I have this line:

`error_log = /var/www/html/myfolder/php_errors.log`

And yet, crashes in the code while the server is running are not logged anywhere. `/var/www/html/myfolder/php_errors.log` exists, but never changes...

What am I missing?

Comment: Can the account that PHP or Apache runs under access that folder?

Comment: Try looking in `/var/log`, and see if there's any information in any of the files there or in the apache/httpd folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable ***error_reporting*** and ***log_errors***?

[Error Settings](http://www.phpknowhow.com/configuration/php-ini-error-settings/)

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#48147)

Comment: That's it. I did not!

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to have the solution by heres what I would look for :

- Try to make sure the path is good *i.e:* maybe you need a `../` to go a bit higher to find the file.
- As [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) said : Check if the folder's permissions to make sure they are correct.
- Less chanches of that but still; check if somewhere in your PHP script you erase the content of the files by mistake during execution.
- Or maybe there somewhere else in the `php.ini` file that rewrite the `error_log` file path. Could happen if someone else has accesss to the files.

Hope it helps -

Comment: I don't know what the correct permissions are. I don't know if Apache2 uses php-fpm or the php-cli directly. I don't know what user the server runs under.